# remove break line before prompt

Tags: unix, prompt

How can I remove the new line before the prompt.
I don't exactly know how to formulate the question, so here's an example.

I want to pass from

```sh
%> echo "hello world"
hello world
%>
```

to

```sh
%> echo "hello world"
hello world%>
```

I tried sed `'s/\\n//'` to subtitute the new line. Even with `\\r` and with `tr`. 
Maybe the cut fonction will be accurate ??

`echo -n` method  I get

```sh
  %> echo -n "hello world"
  hello world%                     #note the new character % just appeared
  %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-n` switch that will not add the eol

```
echo -n "hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this,

```
printf "hello world"
```

Comment: Or, better: `printf '%s' "hello world"`. (Don't pass an arbitrary first argument to `printf` - things can get interesting.)